# Naming huge number of variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to name several variables in Mat lab  like this:

variable1
variable2
variable3
...
variable100

i cant use a 1x100 matrix because each of them is a matrix.

what is the solution to name variables that only different in a number part as i get the example at top.

Comment: well, you can probably create the variables by writing a for loop from 1:100 and use ['variable' num2str(loopIteration)], but I am not sure that is wise.

Comment: Do NOT, ever, use dynamic variable naming. This is very, very bad programming in MATLAB for [several reasons](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F). Please take a look at @excaza 's answer on how to store this in a proper MATLAB way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't want to name your variables like this. You have many options that are much, much better.

Take some example data:

```
A = rand(200);
B = rand(200);
C = rand(200);
```

Each of these is a `200x200` matrix.

MATLAB supports [multidimensional arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html):

```
mydata_matrix(:, :, 1) = A;
mydata_matrix(:, :, 2) = B;
mydata_matrix(:, :, 3) = C;
```

You can nest your data in a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html):

```
mydata_cell{1} = A;
mydata_cell{2} = B;
mydata_cell{3} = C;
```

Or you can use a [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html):

```
mydata(1).data = A;
mydata(2).data = B;
mydata(3).data = C;
```

All of these are easily iterated through and don't pollute your workspace.

Comment: ah, I was gonna ask OP why he cannot represent the data in the multidimensional array format.